# Overlap between codereview and dba

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Originally database design was included in the overall reviewing on CodeReview.SE. However, now that DBA is here, I'm wondering if those questions would be better here. What do you think?

Answer (score 11):

I answered here

https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/are-database-design-reviews-in-scope

I think it depends if you need a "pro" level review or just basics.

- If it's just the basics and you have limited database experience (and there's nothing wrong with the basics) then a generic code review is fine.
- If it's a complex schema and you have lots of database experience, then asking here is preferred.

Remember, the audience is *professional* DBAs on this site -- **database specialists**. If your question is more basic and general, it belongs on Stack Overflow or Code Review, where there are more generalists.

Answer (score 7):

I definitely think that they have a home here. There's a difference between reviewing a class and reviewing a proper table definition including indexes and expected versus actual performance and the like.

Same goes for queries.

I made a Venn for how I view the site currently:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzWbm.png]

Comment: we're so small in this IT world.. I feel so unique. Maybe we're just like dinosaurs .. on our way out? :-).

Comment: Yes. We're so specific even the questions are hard to come by!

Comment: +1 for nice venn diagram. Another example of a picture worth a thousand words.