# MySQL high availability, failover and replication

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

Hello,

Would this forum be appropriate for asking questions on best ways to configure MySQL in a high-availability manner with automated failover, and quick replication? Or would it be serverfault? Any other?

With servers in two data centers *with latency*, the problems I'm looking to address are

- Automated failover from primary data center to secondary data center
- Data synching/replication across the two data centers
- Upon recovery/fail-back to primary data center, quick data synching from secondary server(s) to primary server(s).

Thanks!

KM

Comment: These are the kinds of questions we encourage, actually. So yes, please do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that would definitely be on topic here.

This site is for questions that are of interest to, and can best be answered by, full time database professionals.

Also see my answer here:
[Overlap between codereview and dba](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/overlap-between-codereview-and-dba/189#189)

Answer (score 7):

Your question is very appropriate in this forum. In fact, I wish I saw hundreds of questions like yours in this forum. MySQL DBAs face these things day in and day out.

Comment: THanks @RolandoMySQLDBA. Actually, you answered my question on this topic last week. Thanks again! (-: KM

Comment: I hope this encourages others to take the plunge and openly discuss stuff like this.

Answer (score 4):

So far the questions are mostly developer questions or query optimization questions. 
Which is fine but only a small part of a DBA's job.

Answering more DBA specific questions would be terrific!

Comment: Some of the juicy questions have been asked elsewhere, i.e. ServerFault, StackOverflow, SuperUser. We should just ask in their Meta Sites to Route Their Questions to Us. DBA Infrastructure and Internals? Definitely. Storage Engine choice? Perhaps. Query optimizations? Maybe. Specific Recommendations? OK. Answer question to Do Your Job? Not in DBAStackExchange. Those questions should go to ServerFault, StackOverflow, and SuperUser.

Comment: yeah. A rerouting is in order.